# Clear form fileds after form submission

Tags: javascript, jsp

After I click on submit button,form validation and submission is done,but the form fields are still not cleared. So how to clear fields of form  after submit button is press?

```
function validateContact() {
  var e = document.cform.email.value;
  atpos = e.indexOf("@");
  dotpos = e.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (fn == "" || !isNaN(fn)) {
    alert("Invalid First Name");
    document.cform.fname.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: i am validate the code for registration for eg. email and password,,but where to write the reset code i.e document.form_name.reset();

Comment: Can you please post your code that you have for the `Submit` action?

Comment: function validateContact() 
             {
                 var e=document.cform.email.value;
                  atpos = e.indexOf("@");  dotpos= e.lastIndexOf(".");   
                 if(fn=="" || !isNaN(fn)) 
                 {                   
                    alert("Invalid First Name");
                     document.cform.fname.focus(); 
                     return false; 
                 } 
                
              }
              
           </script>

Comment: like that code is written but where to write document.cform.reset(); for reset the values of form ?

Answer (score -1):

but after you log-in another page is displayed ? so why to clear the log-in screen?
and if the log-in failed, it is good to keep the form as is, so I dont have to re-enter my e.g. email all over again...

Comment: but i have to solve the back button problem....in registration form, after submit the registration form if we press back button so the contents remains same so reset method is use to reset form contents,,where to write it?

Comment: ... but even if you write a java script, I am not sure if a "form autofill" is activited in the browser, that if will be automatically pre-filled anyway...

Comment: sorry i am not getting my answer

Comment: comment for clarification!